# Excel formula to change cell background color and/or set text bold

Tags: html, .net, excel, vba

I have a .net application which generates excel from simple string variable where every cell gets its value like this:

```
For iCol = 0 To Cols.Rows.Count - 1
                str &= Trim(Cols.Rows(iCol)("capt")) & vbTab
            Next
```

I am looking for a way to change cell background and/or set text bold via excel formula.

Something like

```
str &= "=<b>"
str &= Trim(Cols.Rows(iCol)("capt"))
str &= "</b>"
```

or

```
 str &= "=<p bgcolor=" + "color" + ">"
 str &= Trim(Cols.Rows(iCol)("capt"))
 str &= "</p>"
```

Macro or conditional-formatting is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Range.Font`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839770.aspx) and [`Range.Interior`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836210.aspx) properties.

```
For iCol = 0 To Cols.Rows.Count - 1
    str &= Trim(Cols.Rows(iCol)("capt")) & vbTab
    Cells(row, iCol).Font.Bold = True
    Cells(row, iCol).Interior.Color = ColorConstants.vbCyan
Next
```